# Prevent stackframe being created in C#

Tags: c#

I was just doing some reading on performance of recursive functions in csharp. I read that recursive functions are expensive due to stack-frames being created upon each call.

Is there a way to prevent stack frames being created in csharp? I have looked around but I can't seem to find anything that suggests stack-frames can be suppressed for specific calls.

I was hoping that there would be something that I could add into code, perhaps an attribute like follows:

```
[SurpressStackFrame()]
find(int id, Node currentNode) { 

   if(currentNode.id == id) {
      return true;
   }
   return find(id, currentNode.child);
}
```

(p.s. I know I'm not looking at multiple children in this example this is just hypothetical).

Comment: It is called tail call recursion what you want... .NET (the runtime supports it).

Comment: Why not rewrite it as an iterative function if you are concerned about the performance.

Comment: @CSharpie I was just wondering if there was a way to "have my cake and eat it". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called tail call.

There is a tail. instruction in IL, but the C# compiler never uses it. Anyway, it's only a hint to the JIT compiler, and the JIT compiler is smart enough to compile regular recursive method calls as tail calls when possible (it should be possible in the example you posted). As with other JIT optimizations, it only happens in release builds, not in debug.

You can make a simple test:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TailCall(0);
    }
    private static void TailCall(int i)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        TailCall(++i);
    }
}
```

In debug, it will throw a StackOverflowException, in Release it will spin infinitely.

You can find more information about the tail call optimization in .NET in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/clrcodegeneration/2009/05/11/tail-call-improvements-in-net-framework-4/).

Answer (score 2):

In most cases, stack-frames being created is not the performace bottleneck of your code. However, if there is a high level of recursion in the method, one may want to avoid enlarging the stack. This is called the *tail call optimization*, and is done by releasing the current stack frame before calling the inner method.

In your specific example, tail call can be applied to the `return` statement, as the returned value of the inner method call is immediately returned to the caller, and thus a separate stack frame is not necessary.

The only problem is that C# doesn't support tail call (at the moment and probably not in the near future). However, the CLR does support it, so if you can, you could pick a language like F# that is more focused on recursion.

There are also several other options for you - dynamically create a method using CIL that does tail call at the end (however, I am not sure if the expense of calling a dynamic method would be better than calling a normal recursive method in C#).

The best option in this case - don't use recursion at all. The method you provided can be easily rewritten without using recursion at all, and certainly most if not all recursive methods can be rewritten in such a way:

```
bool find(int id, Node currentNode)
{ 
    while(currentNode.id != id)
    {
        currentNode = currentNode.child;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called [tail call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call). It is supported by the .NET runtime (because F# needed it), but there is no support in the C# compiler (even the "new" Roslyn compiler) to do it. See the [request on the github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/1235).

Comment: Thank you I didn't know the term for it.

Comment: But JIT will still do that if it finds appropriate, right? Even without explicit .tail call.

Comment: @Evk Yes, the `.tail` is only a hint... The JIT should tailcall even other methods... I don't know how much aggressively it tries to do it.